# Recent full-point-blunder in a pawn-endgame?

Tags: blunder, pawn-endgame

Does anyone know a game since 2014 with both players at least ELO 2400 containing
 at least one move losing a full point in a pawn endgame ?

In the encyclpopedia for chess endgames, I remember only two examples :
 Eduard Lasker - Moll , Berlin 1904 and Stahlberg - Tartakower , Paris 1934

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example between players rated 2565 and 2498.  I haven't checked this against a tablebase due to the number of pawns, but the move Kb5 changes the Stockfish 6 evaluation from below -100 (at depth 60) to above +11 (at depth 43), which is pretty convincing.

Black has a straightforward win here by first pushing his a-pawn to distract the White king, then capturing White's queenside pawns, then driving his own b-pawn forward to push the White king back, and finally capturing White's kingside pawns and queening one of his own.

But instead Black played Kb5, and White responded by sacrificing a pawn to get his king to d5 to help queen a pawn.  At first sight White's sacrifice may not look too promising, as Black queens first and still has an extra pawn.  But in fact Black is lost due to the advanced position of White's pawns.

```
[Site "Prague"]
[Date "2014.11.29"]
[Round "3.3"]
[White "B. Heberla"]
[Black "Z. Pakleza"]
[Result "1-0"]
[FEN "8/1p3p2/pPk1pPp1/2P3P1/3K1P2/8/8/8 b - - 4 54"]

1...Kb5 2.f5 exf5 3.Kd5 f4 4.Kd6 f3 5.c6 f2 6.c7 f1=Q 7.c8=Q Qd3+ 8.Ke7 Qd5 9.Qe8+ Kxb6 10.Kf8 Qxg5 11.Kxf7 Qh6 12.Kg8 g5 13.Qe3+ Kc6 14.Qe4+ 1-0
```